# Missing / Not found Android.App namespace on Maui

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

I'm trying to migrate my Xamarin project to Maui and I got stuck on finding the equivalent namespace to Android.App.Application.Context on Maui project. The DatabaseHelper class has the following path: MyProject -> Platforms -> Android -> Helpers.

Does anyone know what is the equivalent namespace to Android.App.Application.Context on Maui?

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'App' does not exist in the namespace 'AAT.Platforms.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiEEG.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message is (indirectly) telling you what is wrong:

> The type or namespace name 'App' does not exist in the namespace 'AAT.Platforms.Android'.

This is happening because you are in namespace `AAT.Platforms.Android.Helpers`, which means that `Android` is assumed to mean `AAT.Platforms.Android`.

Here are two ways to access Android.App.Application.Context in this situation:

- `global::Android.App.Application.Context` OR
- `using AndroidApp = Android.App.Application;`
  `AndroidApp.Context`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your namespace to another thing that doesn't include `Android`. Because it's trying to find the class inside your namespace instead of the correct one. So I'd advise you to use `Droid` instead of `Android` in your namespace, i.e. `AAT.Platforms.Droid.Helpers`.
HIH