# Error : Android.Content does not exists Web authenticator

Tags: android, authentication, maui, mobile-development

I am trying to implement Authentication in MAUI Android App (.NET8)

I am following the steps mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android

But getting erorr as *'Content' does not exists*

[image]

Comment: You can also check this case: [What is global::?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022441/what-is-global) to learn more about  `global::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error : Android.Content does not exists...

This is because the naming space produces ambiguity, try to use this:

```cs
global::Android.Content.Intent.ActionView
```

For more info you can refer to this case:
[Missing / Not found Android.App namespace on Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72466281/missing-not-found-android-app-namespace-on-maui).